# ERROR ReferenceError: EnjoyHint is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, enjoyhint

This is tthe error msg i have got.
[image: Error message]

This is my code where the error occurs.
In the - new EnjoyHint({}) line have the error.
Please help me with this.

```
    public initiate(stepName) {
        const steps = data['default'][stepName];
        const block = false;
        if (!block && steps && !(Number(window.innerWidth) < 768)) {
            const enjoyhintInstance = new EnjoyHint({
                onStart: () => {
                    console.log('walk through starts');
                },
                onEnd: () => {
                    console.log('walk through ends');
                },
                onSkip: () => {
                    console.log('Skip all');
                }
            });

            // Check until the element gets binded.
            var i = 1;
            let timer = setInterval(function () {
                if (document.querySelectorAll('.step1').length) {
                    enjoyhintInstance.set(steps);
                    enjoyhintInstance.run();
                    $(".enjoyhint").css({ 'display': 'block' });
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    console.log('timer cleared');
                } else {
                    if (i > 6) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                    }
                    if ($('.enjoyhint').length) {
                        if ($('.enjoyhint').hasClass('enjoyhint_svg_transparent')) {
                            $(".enjoyhint").remove().css({ 'display': 'none' });
                            $('body').css({ overflow: "auto" });
                            $('document').off("touchmove", this.lockTouch);
                        }
                    }
                    console.log('timer not cleared');
                }
                i++;
            }, 500);
        }
    }
```

i have tried of installing package of enjoyhint and jquery.

But i got this error as Enjoyhint is not defined.

I Expecting a result of the Sample page of enjoyhint.

Comment: Did you import `EnjoyHint` ?

Comment: do you mind creating a minimal reproducible issue in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)  ?

Comment: How and where to import that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have not installed it correctly

Or if it is installed, you probably did not **import** it correctly